# How can I know if a circle and a rect is touched in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, geometry, rect

There is a circle and a rect moving on the surface in my program. I want to know if a circle and a rect is touched to each other. It had to be very accurate. I'm sorry for not explaining its detail, but I hope you understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a axis aligned rectangle is given by a top left origin and a width and a height:

```
rect_tl   = (x, y)
rect_size = (width, height)
```

And a circle is given by a center point and a radius:

```
circle_cpt = (x, y)
circle_rad = r
```

If you want to test whether these two shapes overlap, you need to run 2 tests to capture all possible cases.

First it has to be tested if the center point of the circle is inside the rectangle. This can be done by [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) with ease:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(*rect_tl, *rect_size)
isIsect = rect.collidepoint(*circle_cpt)
```

Furthermore it has to be tested if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) corner point of the rectangle is inside the circle. This is the case if the distance between a corner point and the center point of the circle is less than is or equal the radius of the circle. A point can be represented by [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) and the distance between 2 points can be get by [`pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to):

```py
centerPt = pygame.math.Vector2(*circle_cpt)
cornerPts = [rect.bottomleft, rect.bottomright, rect.topleft, rect.topright]
isIsect = any([p for p in cornerPts if pygame.math.Vector2(*p).distance_to(centerPt) <= circle_rad])
```

A function which combines both tests may look like this:

```py
def isectRectCircle(rect_tl, rect_size, circle_cpt, circle_rad):

    rect = pygame.Rect(*rect_tl, *rect_size)
    if rect.collidepoint(*circle_cpt):
        return True

    centerPt = pygame.math.Vector2(*circle_cpt)
    cornerPts = [rect.bottomleft, rect.bottomright, rect.topleft, rect.topright]
    if [p for p in cornerPts if pygame.math.Vector2(*p).distance_to(centerPt) <= circle_rad]:
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: @WKoA But just if "and the circle doesn't move fast enough".